# How to prevent auto input value change with same name and same onchange function in reactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a grading system where I have lists of students and I have to put grades for each student, each input field will have the same onChange function, I have added a demo sandbox here. I want each input field will be unique and only a particular input field will be changed when I will type any grade not to change all rest of the input fields.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-browser-jnono?file=/src/App.js

my code below,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


export default function App() {
  const [grade, setGrade] = useState(null);

  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setGrade(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((m) => (
        <input
          value={grade ? grade : ""}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Enter Grade"
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

here when I type on the first field it will affect the rest of all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it, Just seperated my input to a component as like as below

```
export default function TestInput({ grade, handleChange }) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <input value={grade} onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Enter Grade' />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
 <TestInput
                      value={grade}
                      handleChange={handleChange}
                      placeholder='Enter Grade'
                      style={{ marginTop: "0px" }}
                    />
```

Comment: but how are you going to reference the values later on? for example if you want to access the value for the third input?

Comment: actually, once I type anything to the input and on the right side there is a button, I type and click on the button so the grade state always holds the current value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some things in order to accomplish what you want, first if possible please change the array to contain strings, like this:

```
let arr = [
 "firstInput",
 "secondInput",
 "thirdInput",
 "fourthInput",
 "fifthInput"
];
```

Then you could use the array.reduce to create a initial state object containing, like this

```
const initialState = arr.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ({
    ...acc,
    [curr]: ""
  }),
  {}
);
```

This will create an object that will look like this:

```
{firstInput: "", secondInput: "", thirdInput: "", fourthInput: "", fifthInput: ""}
```

After that you will map the array in your jsx like this:

```
  {arr.map((val) => (
    <InputText
      key={val}
      value={grade[val]}
      name={val}
      handleChange={handleChange}
      placeholder="Enter Grade"
    />
  ))}
```

Here you can notice that you need to pass a name prop to your input so you will have to update the input component to accept the name prop and pass it like this:

```
export default function Input({ name, grade, handleChange }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={grade}
        // name prop that will link the input with the state object value
        name={name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Enter Grade"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Last but not least in your handleChange function please do this:

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setGrade({
      ...grade,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
```

Basically the function will update the initial state but only with the key that matches the input name. so everything that is not the input you're typing it will stay the same.

Here's the forked sandbox in case you want to take a look:

https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-worker-pvyl2

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a unique name to each input field so that you can refer to each field with its name.

Here is the one approach that you can follow:

```
  export default function App() {
  const [grade, setGrade] = useState({});

  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setGrade({
      ...grade,
      name: e.target.name,
      value: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((m, i) => (
        <InputText
          key={m}
          grade={grade[`name${m}`]}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Enter Grade"
          name={`name${m}`}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have named all these fields as name1, name2, name3, and so on. But if you want to give a descriptive name, then you can modify your array like this:

```
let arr = ["firstField", "secondField", .......]
```

and pass name to input field as `name={m}`

Answer (score 0):

I saw your codes on codesanbox. you shoud consider grade variable as an Array because the grade is a set of value not a single;

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import InputText from "./Input";

export default function App() {
  const [grades, setGrades] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    let newGrades = [...grades]
    newGrades[i] = e.target.value
    setGrades(newGrades);
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(grades)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {[...Array(6)].map((m, i) => (
        <InputText
          handleChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
          placeholder="Enter Grade"
          key={i}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>Log Grades</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```